# Postfix does not receive mail from outside

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I have installed postfix/dovecot/postfixadmin using the following guide
https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/setup-basic-postfix-mail-sever-ubuntu

I have set up virtual domains.
I am able to receive configure a mail client with a mailbox in one of the virtual domains and send mail, to receive mail from my server, but not from outside.

I have found something close in
[Dovecot / Postfix / SASL: Connect to /var/run/dovecot/auth-client failed: Permission denied](https://serverfault.com/questions/671232/dovecot-postfix-sasl-connect-to-var-run-dovecot-auth-client-failed-permis)

but removing the chrooting did not work for me.

Here is an excerpt of my postfix main.cf

````
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
compatibility_level = 2
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
myhostname = mydomain
mydomain = domain.tld
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain , localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
smtputf8_enable = no
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps =
   proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf,
   proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps =
   proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf,
   proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_maps.cf,
   proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_catchall_maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_minimum_uid = 2000
virtual_uid_maps = static:2000
virtual_gid_maps = static:2000
local_recipient_maps =
home_mailbox = Maildir/
policyd-spf_time_limit = 3600
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
   permit_mynetworks,
   permit_sasl_authenticated,
   reject_unauth_destination,
   check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes```

When I run 
sudo doveadm auth test my username
I get 
`auth-client: conn unix:/var/run/dovecot/auth-client: connect(/var/run/dovecot/auth-client) failed: Connection refused`
````

Comment: Do you get any error messages when you try to send an email form outside?

Comment: No I don't get any messages. I have tried to look at a new tutorial on  https://linuxize.com/post/install-and-configure-postfix-and-dovecot/. and I have added the email postmaster address in 20-lmtp.conf and also added smtpd_recipient_restrictions in postfix/main.cf. Now protocols are listed twice like imap lmtp imap lmtp in dovecot -n

Comment: Then I get [private/dovecot-lmtp]: Connection refused

Comment: I also get  postfix/smtpd  fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms

Comment: Did you restart postfix after the configuration changes? Can you please add the output of the command `ss -lnt|grep :25` **to your question**.

Comment: LISTEN 0      100                              0.0.0.0:25          0.0.0.0:*                                                                                    
LISTEN 0      100                                 [::]:25             [::]:*

Comment: I also discovered that I had saved some configurations in dovecot/conf.d and that they were duplicated. I removed them

Comment: Can you please add the output of `grep -vE '^\s*(|#.*)$' /etc/postfix/main.cf` formatted to your question, not in the comments.

Comment: Did you set up MX DNS records for your domain? It is crucial for other e-mail systems to find out your to deliver mail.

Comment: yes, and last week it could work. Now my problem is Error: auth-client: conn unix:/var/run/dovecot/auth-client: connect(/var/run/dovecot/auth-client) failed: Connection refused

Comment: I can't understand how this error message relates to Postifx. Where did you found it?